# Explain how XMLBeans Handles '-' Character

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlbeans

I have a file with an XSD element which contains a '-' character.  This is a recent change to the XSD file and after compiling the file I am seeing no change to the accessor method used in my java code.  Additionally when I attempt to call this element in my java code it throws a null pointer exception.  I receive no errors compiling the xsd file, I have restarted and cleaned my project multiple times.

Can someone please explain how XMLBeans is handling the addition of the '-' character, or how I can better handle this situation?

Example:

Old:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FooBoo">
```

Old Accessor Method:

```
getFooBoo();
```

New:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Foo-Boo">
```

New Accessor Method:

```
getFooBoo();
```

Expected New Accessor Method:
    getFoo_Boo();

Answer (score 0):

XmlBeans generates the getter and setter method names by splitting the XSD property name into word parts, capitalizing each part, and the combining the words together.  Any non-word characters are considered word part boundaries and will be skipped.

The exact details of the algorithm can be found in [StscJavaizer.pickJavaPropertyName()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.4.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/StscJavaizer.java#StscJavaizer.pickJavaPropertyName%28java.util.Set,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) and [NameUtil.upperCamelCase()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.4.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/common/NameUtil.java#NameUtil.upperCamelCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks!  This didn't quite resolve the issue I am having, and I think it could just be related to the version of xmlbeans I am using (2.4.0) I am now just doing a string.replace on the tag name and removed the '-' from my xsd.